# Target class [ ] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, class, target

I see this question a lot, and I tried many of the solutions but none seems to help. I hope that with my code shown I'll be able to work it out!

This is my route:

```
Route::view('/', 'pages.home');
Route::view('about', 'pages.about');
//Route::view('shop', 'shop.shop');
Route::get('shop', 'App\Http\Controllers\Shop\ShopController@displayShop');
```

and this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Shop;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Category;

class ShopController extends Controller
{
    public function displayShop() {
        $data['categories'] = Category::getCategories();
        return view('shop,shop', $data);
    }
}
```

And here is where my file is located
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM4as.png

thank you for your help!

Comment: Based on your title I guess `Category::getCategories()` will return an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using Laravel 8, the new way to call controllers from route is

```
Route::get('shop', [ShopController::class, 'displayShop']);
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much!